# sorting a dictionary values by part name..!

Tags: python, dictionary, maya

I'm a little new to python so please pardon me!

I have a material that's assigned to an object but also on other faces in a different object. I store all the faces into a dictionnary, i.e. :

```
mydic = { "aiStandard" : ["pSphere1.f[1:20]", "pSphere1.f[22:28]", "pSphere2.f[35:59]"] }
```

In my dictionnary, I want to filter the value of "aiStandard" to get only "pSphere1"'s faces or any other wanted object.

please don't hesitate to let me know!

Thanks

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

as they told you, you are not giving a lot of information or code to test...

selecting is working if your dic look like this :

```
mydic = { "aiStandard" : ["pSphere1.f[1:20]", "pSphere1.f[22:28]", "pSphere2.f[35:59]"] }

cmds.select(mydic["aiStandard"])
```

if you want to filter your values, here is a sample code:

```
def filterObj(objs=list, filterName=str):
    return [i for i in objs if i.startswith(filterName)]
objs = []
for i in mydic["aiStandard"]:
    objs.append(i.split('.')[0])
objs = list(set(objs))    

for obj in objs:
    print(obj, filterObj(mydic["aiStandard"], obj))
```